# About decompiler

Tags: vb.net, decompiling, decompiler

i try to open .exe something (i think visual basic language)

ex.

```
Private Class JtoJyfwFywdp0oMhf7T82oYvUAlifLO1N3P64NAlifLO1N3P64NAT9q3iTiG85jA
    Private YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0 As String()

    Private hnpXEECHeSKX2l6BD3S1H70sRAl6BD3S1H70sRAObgZQEm4Lcg3A2YKefpb5kBYA As XNamespace()

    Private 2YKefpb5kBYM3tOXycdgIwnyAAyLV2mDpIfM9uAyLV2mDpIfM9uACCAOK0G5Sxe0 As List(Of XAttribute)

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Friend Sub New(inScopePrefixes As String(), inScopeNs As XNamespace(), attributes As List(Of XAttribute))
        Me.YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0 = inScopePrefixes
        Me.hnpXEECHeSKX2l6BD3S1H70sRAl6BD3S1H70sRAObgZQEm4Lcg3A2YKefpb5kBYA = inScopeNs
        Me.2YKefpb5kBYM3tOXycdgIwnyAAyLV2mDpIfM9uAyLV2mDpIfM9uACCAOK0G5Sxe0 = attributes
    End Sub
```

.... have The way to understand it ?

```
Private YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0
Me.YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0
```

i know it for variable but i want to know a real variable

estimated

```
Private YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0 = Private model1 As String()
Me.YWWmY1YGZHRJ1YWWmY1YGZHRJAcyz5jqj3lGWaAXJ0BrSt4pTmrAXJ0BrSt4pTm0 = me.model1
```

Comment: Pretty strong sign that the owner of this code does not want you do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **reverse engineering**, which is **stealing someone else's work**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That *is* (or *was*) the real member names when it was compiled.

The problem is this particular code was [*obfuscated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) before it was compiled. As such, the original source code names are *unrecoverable* without an additional mapping.

> Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to conceal its purpose (security through obscurity) or its logic, in order to prevent tampering, *[and] deter reverse engineering* ..

In this case, a manual mapping can even be applied: "2YKe...Sxe0" means "attributes", as evidence by the assignment from a [named] parameter. But this manual reversal is very tiresome, e.g. what is the purposeful name of the class?